# is there any way to clear the content of a text file dynamically in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am using ofstream to output some text to a file in `ios::app` mode within a loop. But after some step, I need to clear the content of the file. I know we can do it by either delete the file and open again or to open it again with `ios::trunc`, but is there any where I can get it done without close and open the file again?

Comment: You're asking for a way to avoid two simple lines of code?

Comment: Why would you want to write something to a file, only to delete it again, all inside a loop?

Comment: The file was used to store a temporary status of the program output used for debug. But the output information is too much about 300 M at a time. I will store some status every 10 loops. This information will only be used for debug (until some message appear). Since the whole program loop for million times, if each time to open the file and close it again, it will be so slow.

Comment: There's a standard C temporary file, by the way, why not just overwrite that file? Start at the beginning again, who cares about clearing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have opened it in `ios::app` mode, there's no way to clear content without opening it again. `ofstream` can only put text in a file, and as text files are sequential, you can't directly erase data on them.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if it is possible with io streams, but in general you can truncate an open file by setting its current position to 0 and then setting the EOF marker on the file.  In the Win32 API, for instance, you can do that with `SetFilePointer()` and `SetEndOfFile()`.